# Error en cookies

Tags: php, html, css

Estoy realizando un carrito en PHP y me funciona absolutamente todo, a excepción de las cookies, que no me gestiona bien los pedidos.

Cuando ejecuto el inicio.php y almaceno todos los productos, el carrito se ocupa de gestionarlos, almacena bien el precio y detecta que el carrito tiene almacenado dichos artículos, no obstante, cuando paso a gestionarlo, creo que obvia el contenido o tengo algo en mi código de cookies que provoque que no detecte nada.

La idea es que salga en numero de pedidos pues 1 y, si voy realizando más, que se me acumulen además de la fecha de realización, pero no lo hace.

Edit: También me he dado cuenta que al pulsar el botón deshacer el pedido, la fecha aumenta, cosa bastante extraña.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto mi código para una mejor observación:

```
<?php
    //INICIO DE LA PÁGINA
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tienda</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/site.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Architects+Daughter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<!--CREAMOS NUESTRO FORMULARIO DE PRODUCTOS-->
<h1 class="font-italic">¡Bienvenido!</h1>
<!--LE DAMOS EL METODO POST PARA QUE TOME LOS DATOS EL CARRITO-->
    <form action="carrito.php" method="POST">
        <p>Selecciona el producto que quieres comprar:</p>
        <!--AGREGAMOS DENTRO DEL VALUE LOS DATOS QUE VAMOS A RECOGER-->
            <select class="form-control w-25" name="articulo">
                <option value="Libreta-1.50">Libreta</option>
                <option value="Boligrafo-0.50">Boligrafo</option>
                <option value="Grapadora-3.00">Grapadora</option>
                <option value="Tijera-0.90">Tijera</option>
                <option value="Carpeta-0.20">Carpeta</option>
                <option value="Cartulina-0.10">Cartulina</option>
                <option value="Estuche-5.50">Estuche</option>
                <option value="Mochila-10.00">Mochila</option>
                <option value="Rotulador-0.20">Rotulador</option>
                <option value="Goma-0.05">Goma</option>
                <option value="Fichero-2.00">Fichero</option>
            </select>
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="number">¿Cuantos quieres comprar?</label>
                            <br/>
                            <input type="number" name="number" id="number" size="15" max="10" min="1" value="0">
                    </div>
                    <div>   
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Añadir al carrito" name="botonAñadir">
                            <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='http://localhost/DWS/CARRITO_CORRECTO/';" class="btn btn-danger" value="Salir"/>
                    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Agregar productos

```
<?php

        session_start();

        // COMPRUEBO SI EXISTE EL BOTON, SI EXISTE RECOJO LOS DATOS
        if (isset($_POST['botonAñadir'])) 
        {

            if (empty($_POST['articulo'])) 
            {

            } 
            else 
            {
                $nombre = explode("-", $_POST['articulo']);
                $titulo = $nombre[0];
                $number = $_POST['number'];
                $precio = $nombre[1];

                // SI NO EXISTE SESIÓN LA CREA, SINO AÑADE LOS PRODUCTOS
                if (!isset($_SESSION['tienda'])) {
                    $_SESSION['tienda'] = [];
                }
                $_SESSION['tienda'][] = [$titulo, $number, $precio];
                // RECORRO CON UN FOR PARA COMPROBAR SI EXISTE YA EL TITULO, Y SI EXISTE SUMAMOS LA CANTIDAD ANTERIOR
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['tienda']) - 1; $i++) 
                {
                    if ($_SESSION['tienda'][$i][0] == $titulo) {
                        $_SESSION['tienda'][$i][1] += $number;
                        unset($_SESSION['tienda'][count($_SESSION['tienda']) - 1]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Carrito de la compra</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/site.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Architects+Daughter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['tienda'])) 
            {
                echo "<img src='assets/img/carrito.png' class='imagen_Carrito'/>";
            }
            //SESIÓN NO INICIADA
            else 
            {
                echo "<img src='assets/img/error.png' class='imagen_Carrito'/>";
                echo "<br/>";
                echo "<p class='alertaError bg-warning Width 25% text-center'>ERROR: HAS ACCEDIDO A CARRITO DIRECTAMENTE</p>"; 
                header('Refresh: 2; URL=inicio.php');
            }
                ?>

        <?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['tienda'])) 
        {
        ?>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <h4>Resumen de pedido:</h4>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre del producto</th>
                        <th>number</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>

                    <?php
                    $precioTotal = [];
                    if (isset($titulo) && ($number) && ($precio)) 
                    {
                        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['tienda']); $i++) 
                        {
                            $precioTotal[] = $_SESSION['tienda'][$i][1] * $_SESSION['tienda'][$i][2];
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>" . $_SESSION['tienda'][$i][0] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $_SESSION['tienda'][$i][1] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $_SESSION['tienda'][$i][2] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $precioTotal[$i] . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>ERROR, INTRODUCE UN TÍTULO. VUELVE A EMPEZAR.</td>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                        session_unset();
                        header('Refresh: 2; URL=inicio.php');
                    }
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-light" colspan="2">Total:</th>
                        <th class="text-light">
                            <?php
                            echo "<td>" . array_sum($precioTotal) . "</td>";
                            ?>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
<?php
        } 
        else 
        
        {
?>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <h4>Resumen de pedido:</h4>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre del producto</th>
                <th>number</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p>ERROR, VUELVE A EMPEZAR.</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php
        }
?>

        <form action="pedidos.php" method="POST">
            <input type="button" value="Seguir comprando" onclick="location.href='inicio.php'"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Gestionar pedido" name="gestionar"onclick="window.location.href='pedidos.php'"/> 
        </form>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Deshacer pedido

```
<?php


session_start();
session_unset();

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');

$suma = 0;

if (empty($_SESSION['tienda'])) {
    setcookie('fecha', date("d/m/y G:i:s"));
}

if (isset($_POST['Gestionar'])) {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['pedidos'])) {
        $suma = 1;
        setcookie('pedidos', $suma);
    } else {
        $suma++;
        $suma = $_COOKIE['pedidos'] + $suma;
        setcookie('pedidos', $suma);
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['btnDeshacerPedido'])) {
    $suma = $_COOKIE['pedidos'] - 1;
    setcookie('pedidos', $suma);
    if($_COOKIE['pedidos'] ==0){
        $suma = 0;
        setcookie('pedidos', $suma);
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['btnBorrarHistorial'])) {
    $suma = 0;
    setcookie('pedidos', $suma);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Pedidos</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/site.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Architects+Daughter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="bg-secondary">
    <div class="text-center bg-dark">
        <a><b class="text-info text-warning" style="font-size:30px;">
                <?php
                if (!isset($_SESSION['tienda'])) 
                {
                    
                }
                ?></b></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="container mt-5 contenedores">
            <?php
            if (isset($_COOKIE['pedidos'])) {

                echo "Numero de pedidos: " . $suma . "<br/>";
                echo "Fecha del último pedido: " . $_COOKIE['fecha'] . "<br/>";
            } else if (!isset($_COOKIE['pedidos'])) {
                echo "Numero de pedidos: 0<br/>";
                echo "Fecha del último pedido: " . $_COOKIE['fecha'] . "<br/>";
            }
            ?>
            <div class="row justify-content-center col-12">
                <div class="text-center mt-3 pl-4">
                    <form action="pedidos.php" method="POST">
                        <input type="submit" value="Deshacer pédido" name="btnDeshacerPedido" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Borrar historial" name="btnBorrarHistorial" />
                        <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='inicio.php';" value="Regresar a Inicio" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo del todo tu lógica, pero el primer error que veo es que no estás proporcionando fecha de expiración de las [cookies](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.setcookie.php) y eso hace que se borren al cerrar el navegador. Aparte, al eliminar el pedido, también eliminas todas las variables de sesión y es por eso que la fecha se incrementa.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias, ya he conseguido que se sume correctamente y se acumulen los pedidos bien, pero sigo sin conseguir arreglar el problema de la fecha, no logro ver que es lo que lo provoca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La fecha se reinicia porque, como te dije en comentarios, estás eliminando las variables de sesión:

```
<?php
// Inicio de sesión, es correcto
session_start();
// Aquí borras las variables de sesión
session_unset();

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');

$suma = 0;
// Ya borraste las variables de sesión, siempre entrará aquí
if (empty($_SESSION['tienda'])) {
    setcookie('fecha', date("d/m/y G:i:s"));
}
```

En todo caso, cambia esa comprobación para crear la cookie solo si no existe:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['fecha'])) {
    setcookie('fecha', date("d/m/y G:i:s"));
}
```

Solo recuerda enviar el parámetro que desees para expiración.

Finalmente, para poner la fecha del último pedido, en el script donde agregas productos tienes esto:

```
// SI NO EXISTE SESIÓN LA CREA, SINO AÑADE LOS PRODUCTOS
if (!isset($_SESSION['tienda'])) {
    // Estás creando la variable de sesión
    $_SESSION['tienda'] = [];
    // Es un nuevo pedido, actualiza la cookie de fecha
    setcookie('fecha', date("d/m/y G:i:s"));
}
```

Comment: Buenas, perdón por la tardanza, he realizado los cambios que me has dicho, pero la fecha y hora se me ha quedado estancada y no marca la diferencia de tiempo entre los pedidos que he realizado.

Comment: @Puntoycoma, edité la respuesta para decirte dónde actualizar la fecha.

Comment: ¡Muchisimas gracias!, disculpa si he dado mucho la lata, soy un novato con PHP.

Comment: @Puntoycoma, no te preocupes, todos estamos aquí para aprender y me da gusto que por fin lo hayas solucionado.